# How to print the exact name of the expression from a thrown exception in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

I don't know how to print the exact name of the expression from the thrown exception in my code: http://pastie.org/private/jfszprszt7uxng2ajahcg

What I need is that it prints `WrongTypeInExpression(BinOp("+",Var("b"),IntLit(12)))` but actually it prints `WrongTypeInExpression(BinOp(+,Var(b),IntLit(12)))`.

Could you help me please?

I have tried to change to these things but they produce the same result:

```
case e:WrongTypeInExpression => println("WrongTypeInExpression(" + e.expr.toString() + ")")
```

Comment: That is not _the exact name_.  That is _the source code that caused the exception_.  Anyway, if you don't like how case classes print things out, you can override their `toString` method by hand.

Comment: Could you tell me your toString implementation here?
Thank you for your answer :) .

Comment: I don't have a `toString` implementation.  I'm just pointing out that you could write one that does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the purpose of showing the issue, your code on pastie.org can be shortened to:

```
trait Expr
case class BinOp(op: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr
case class IntLit(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr

println(BinOp("+", Var("b"), IntLit(12))) // prints BinOp(+,Var(b),IntLit(12))
```

As Rex Kerr notes in his comment, you can simply override toString (which is silently called in the println above to convert all its arguments to printable values) to do what you want.

```
trait Expr
case class BinOp(op: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr {
    override def toString : String = "BinOp(\"" + op + "\", " + left.toString + ", " + right.toString + ")"
}
case class IntLit(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr {
    override def toString : String = "Var(\"" + name + "\")"
}
```

now, as you wished:

```
scala> println(BinOp("+", Var("b"), IntLit(12)))
BinOp("+", Var("b"), IntLit(12))
```

Comment: Thank you, Paolo Falabella :) .